# How to use AWS CDK CodePipeline without an oauthToken?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have previously created a CodePipeline for building from a private GitHub Repo as below:

```ts
pipeline.addStage({
  stageName: 'Source',
  actions: [
    new GitHubSourceAction({
      actionName: 'Checkout',
      owner: github.ardcOwner, 
      repo: github.raidoSrcRepo,
      branch: "main",
      oauthToken: SecretValue.secretsManager('personal-token' ),
      output: outputSources,
      trigger: GitHubTrigger.NONE,
    }),
  ],
});
```

The repo in question is now public.
Given that no webhook is needed, since the trigger is set to `NONE` - how do I create new `GitHubSourceAction` *without* providing the `oauthToken` property?

The property is mandatory.
Is there a way to provide a "dummy" value to the `GitHubSourceAction` for `oauthToken` such that the account doesn't need to have an unnecessary/unused secret?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to provide a dummy value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use a dummy value (as opposed to dummy "Secret"):

```
oauthToken: SecretValue.unsafePlainText("dummy"),
```

But that failed with "Could not access the GitHub repository".

It was then I remembered that CodePipeline doesn't do a clone, it downloads a zip archive of the HEAD of the repo.

Presumably, CodePipeline needs the secret to download the zip archive from GitHub.

So I don't think CodePipeline can be used with a public GitHub repo without using an OAuth token.